# Firefox stored cached incomplete response

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, caching, https

I just found a partial response being cached as complete in one of our customer's machines, which rendered the whole website unusable. And I have absolutely no idea, what could possible have gone wrong there.

So what could have possibly gone wrong in the following setup?

On the server-side, we have an ASP.NET-application running. One IHttpHandler handles requests to javascript-files. It basically minifies the files as they are requested and writes the result on the response-stream. It does also log the length of the string being written to the Response-Stream:

```
String javascript = /* Javascript is retrieved here */;
HttpResponse response = context.Response;
response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
HttpCachePolicy cache = response.Cache;
cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
cache.SetMaxAge(TimeSpan.FromDays(300));
cache.SetETag(ETag);
cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(300));
cache.SetLastModified(LastModified);
cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.None);
response.Headers.Add("Vary", "Accept-Encoding");
Log.Info("{0} characters sent", javascript.length);
response.Write(javascript);
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

The content is then normally sent using gzip-encoding with chunked transfer-encoding. Seems simple enough to me.

Unfortunately, I just had a remote-session with a user, where only about 1/3 of the file was in the cache, which broke the file of course (15k instead of 44k). In the cache, the content-encoding was also set to gzip, all communication took place via https.

After having opened the source-file on the user's machine, I just hit Ctrl-F5 and the full content was displayed immediately.

What could have possibly gone wrong?

In case it matters, please find the cache-entry from Firefox below:

```
Cache entry information
key:    <resource-url>
fetch count:    49
last fetched:   2015-04-28 15:31:35
last modified:  2015-04-27 15:29:13
expires:    2016-02-09 14:27:05
Data size:  15998 B
Security:   This is a secure document.
security-info: (...)
request-method:     GET
request-Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
response-head:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=25920000
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Tue, 09 Feb 2016 14:27:12 GMT
Last-Modified: Tue, 02 Jan 2001 11:00:00 GMT
Etag: W/"0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 13:27:12 GMT
necko:classified:   1
```

Comment: Update: After some time, I gave up. The minified js-files are now written to the file-system with a unique name and served directly by IIS from there. The problem did not occur ever since.

Answer (score 0):

Your clients browser is most likely caching the JavaScript files which would mean the src of your scripts isn't changing.

For instance if you were to request myScripts

```
<script src="/myScripts.js">
```

Then the first time, the client would request that file and any further times the browser would read its cache.

You need to append some sort of unique value such as a timestamp to the end of your scripts so even if the browser caches the file, the new timestamp will act like a new file name.

The client receives the new scripts after pressing Ctrl+F5 because this is a shortcut to empty the browsers cache.

MVC has a really nice way of doing this which involves appending a unique code which changes everytime the application or it's app pool is restarted. Check out [MVC Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did all the versioning already: For a particular URL the server will always return the same javascript. If the Javascript changes, the src in the script-tag will change too. But unfortunately, the client still cached only a third of the actual content (the content just stops in the middle of a string, leaving the quotation marks open).